# Войти или зайти?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В дом заходят или входят, надо ли различать эти глаголы? Есть мнение, что обычно в дверь, комнату и дом входят, а говорить "разрешите зайти" неприлично.

Тем не менее, в литературе достаточно часто встречается глагол "зайти", например:

К счастью, никто так и не зашел в дом (А. А. Фадеев).  Так вот, я зашел в дом, где мы жили тогда (А. С. Грин). Чепурный зашел в дом и лег в темноте отдохнуть и сосредоточиться (А. П. Платонов).

А как говорите вы?

Спасибо за ваше внимание и ваши ответы.

Comment: В повседневной речи  я употребляю "зайти''.

Comment: Странно, что никто не затронул слова "войти" и "зайти" в их современном контексте, т.е. в отношении интернет-форумов.
Понятно, что вообще возможны оба варианта — "зайти" или "войти" на форум. Но какое слово будет более предпочтительным по правилам русского языка? PS: не встречал по этому поводу ни один филологический, твёрдо обоснованный ответ.

Comment: @algri14 так задайте вопрос! https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 3):

ЗАЙТИ - 2. во что. Войти, проникнуть куда-л. З. через дверь, через калитку. З. ***в дом,*** в комнату, в подъезд. З. в реку.

> Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
>   Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.

Примечательно то, что это значение не во всех словарях есть.

зайти - (о речи) возникнуть, начаться
Пример: Зашел разговор о чем-н.

---

2. - прийти куда-нибудь за кем-чем-нибудь, чтобы взять с собой
     Пример: З. за книгой. З. за приятелем.

     ---
3. - идя, попасть куда-нибудь далеко, за какой-нибудь предел
     Пример: З. в тыл. З. в лес. З. по горло в воду. З. за угол. Солнце зашло за тучи или солнце зашло (скрылось за горизонтом). Беседа зашла за полночь (перен.). Спор зашел слишком далеко (перен. : перешел границы допустимого).

     ---
4. - подойти не прямо, обходя, со стороны
     Пример: З. от леса. З. справа.

     ---
5. - идя, по пути побывать где-нибудь- посетить кого-нибудь
     Пример: З. в магазин. З. к приятелю. Зайди вечерком, нужно поговорить. Зайдите через недельку.

     ---
6. - а также вообще прийти к кому-нибудь, посетить кого-нибудь
     Пример: З. в магазин. З. к приятелю. Зайди вечерком, нужно поговорить. Зайдите через недельку.

> Толковый словарь Ожегова.

ов. неперех.

4) ***а) Войти, проникнуть куда-л., во что-л.***

> Ефремова Т.Ф. Толковый словарь русского языка.

побывать где-н., посетить кого-н., а также (разг.) вообще прийти к кому-н.,
посетить кого-н.
3. в магазин.
3. к приятелю. Зайди вечеркам, нужно
поговорить. Зайдите через недельку.
2. за кем-чем. Прийти куда-н. за
кем-чем-н., чтобы взять с собой.
3. за книгой.
3. за приятелем.
3. Подойти
не прямо, обходя, со стороны.
3. от леса.
3. справа.
4. Идя, попасть куда-н.
далеко, за какой-н. предел.
3. в тыл.
3. в лес.
3. по горло в воду.
3. за
угол. Солнце зашло за тучи или солнце зашло (скрылось за горизонтом). Беседа
зашла за полночь (перен.). Спор зашел слишком далеко (перен.: перешел
границы допустимого).
5. (1 и 2 л. не употр.). О речи: возникнуть, начаться.
Зашел разговор о чем-н. II несов. заходить, -ожу, -одишь. II многокр.
захаживать, -аю, -аешь (к 1 и 2 знач.). II суш, заход, -а, м. (к 1, 3 и 4
знач.) и захождение, -я, ср. (к 3 и 4 знач.).

> С.И.Ожегов, Н.Ю.Шведова. Толковый словарь русского языка.

Comment: Серж, интересно, что Ефремова считает разговорным вариантом: зайти к приятелю, а не прийти к нему (но это совсем разный смысл). Или надо говорить: посетить приятеля, побывать у него.

Comment: Мнение Ефремовой не всегда совпадает с мнением других лингвистов.

Answer (score 3):

Для меня эти глаголы заметно отличаются друг от друга. Глагол "войти: "я вошёл в дом", "они вошли в подъезд", "разрешите войти", "коллеги вошли в офис","в комнату неожиданно вошла тёща" и т.п. Глагол "зайти" употребляется, по-моему, в других ситуациях: "она зашла к нему по дороге на работу", "давай зайдём в магазин", "враг зашёл с тыла", "Иванова, зайдите к директору", "если поедешь в центр, зайди проведать дядю Петра" и т.п. Если попытаться объяснить, какое у этих глаголов главное смысловое отличие, то "войти", на мой взгляд, означает проникновение (не могу подобрать более точное слово) в какое-то закрытое пространство (в какое-то помещение), а "зайти" имеет похожее значение, но со смысловым оттенком временности этого "проникновения". Заходят на какое-то время, ненадолго. У глагола "войти" смыслового оттенка временности, по-моему, нет.

Comment: Вы правы, указывая на значение ограниченности времени, которое придает глаголу приставка ЗА. Но часто выбор глагола зависит от контекста, они не всегда взаимозаменяемы.

Answer (score 3):

Большое спасибо за ответы, все они оказались для меня очень полезными.

Всё-таки наши филологи, которые составляют словари и учат нас культуре речи далеко не всегда внимательны к языку и точны в своих наблюдениях.

Ознакомившись с вашими материалами, еще раз перечитав т. Скворцова (автора "Культуры русской речи"), я начинаю думать, что между "войти и зайти" **семантическая разница намного больше, чем стилистическая**, то есть замена одного глагола другим в принципе возможна не часто.

Как мне кажется, приставка ЗА придает действию два дополнительных значения: **пространственное и временное.** С точки зрения **пространства**, зайти - это, действительно, войти и пройти дальше. С точки зрения **времени**, зайти можно на ограниченный временной отрезок. Если по контексту нет особой необходимости подчеркивать эти значения, то можно сказать: "Чепурный зашел (вошел) в дом и лег в темноте отдохнуть и сосредоточиться".

Но замену можно сделать не всегда: "К счастью, никто так и не зашел в дом". В этом случае нельзя сказать "вошел". И как правило, именно контекст, а не стиль определяют выбор нужного глагола.

А как насчет речевых ошибок? "Едва я зашел в дверь, которую считал коридорной, как ставня отворилась".  Здесь, мне кажется, "зашел" не совсем подходит: разговорный, неточный стиль. Разрешите войти? - это правильно, вежливо. А "разрешите зайти"? Ну да, зайти, остаться, на сколько надо, и ходить, где хочется. Нет, так говорить не стоит.

Но это мои собственные рассуждения, возможно, вы не согласитесь с ними.

Comment: Вера, я с вами согласен. Но, на мой взгляд, чтобы быть абсолютно уверенным, нужно провести серьезный анализ.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы ответил так. Войти в узком смысле - переступить порог. Зайти - это уже "чуть подальше", войти и пройти, что ли? На практике эти два глагола, войти и зайти, в смысле проникания в помещение не различаются и легко взаимозаменяются. Другие их значения расходятся достаточно серьезно : "вошел в долю", но "зашел слишком далеко". О том, что фраза *разрешите зайти* неправильная - впервые слышу. Такой рафинированный запрет сам по себе неправилен и *неприличен*.

Comment: Зайти - это войти и пройти дальше. Мне кажется, Вы очень верно отметили пространственный аспект в значении глагола "зайти", обычно говорят только  о временных особенностях приставки ЗА.

Answer (score 2):

Выбор слова (войти или зайти) во многих случаях закрепляется за ситуацией. В дверь "входят", в дом или иное здание в одних случаях "входят", в других - "заходят". Если вы сидите дома, к вам в дом может без предупреждения "зайти" (но не "войти") друг; в другом случае он сначала позвонит и позже вы сможете увидеть в окно как он "входит" (хуже "заходит") в ваш дом; затем он "входит" в квартиру, раздевается и т.д. Вы можете по дороге на работу "зайти" в магазин, но уже "войдя" в него, вспомнить, что не выключили паяльник. В подобных случаях без ущерба для стиля нельзя менять местами глаголы, но вряд ли возможно обобщение, подходящее для правила. Можно лишь утверждать, что глагол "войти" несёт только смысл физического действия, в то время как глагол "зайти" может иметь добавочный смысл (например, своё намерение "прийти ненадолго", заглянуть по дороге; при наблюдении за кем-то со стороны улицы - "идти и скрыться из виду, войдя в дверь какого-то дома").

Что касается выражения "разрешите зайти" (если это просьба в реальном времени), для меня оно звучит просторечно - как искажение устойчивого выражения.

Comment: Мы тут обсуждали уже разные случаи, когда используется тот или другой глагол. Интересно четко обозначить именно те моменты, когда смешение значений нежелательно, грамматически неточно и нужно выбрать только одно подходящее слово. Вот почему "разрешите войти" - это устойчивое (и правильное) выражение, а "разрешите зайти" - это уже искажение. Или в общем виде: в каких конкретных ситуациях следует быть осторожным, чтобы не нарушить правильность речи?

Comment: Александр, через дверь можно и зайти. Об этом свидетельствует словарная фиксация. А в остальном  - согласен. Обычно тот или иной глагол в одном и том же значении закрепляется за ситуацией.

Comment: Через дверь "зайти" можно только в помещение (названное или подразумеваемое), но в дверь "входят".

Comment: Вера, я думаю, что систематизация возможна только в словаре сочетаемости - настолько разнообразны причины, по которым выбирают одно или другое. На вопрос "разрешите войти" можно ответить формально "входите", но гораздо вежливее звучит "заходите": дополнительно подразумевается либо "вас ждали", либо "да, уже можно; мы для того тут и сидим, чтобы посетителей принимать". Здесь об одном и том же действии с разных позиций говорят по-разному.

Comment: Александр, если честно, не понял: ''Через дверь "зайти" можно только в помещение (названное или подразумеваемое)''. А что, когда говорят войти в дверь - разве не имеется в виду помещение?

Comment: При этом предлоге действие глагола направлено на помещение (оно может быть названо или - при недоговорке - подразумеваться), а не на дверь. Во втором случае за дверью может оказаться даже пропасть; "войти в дверь" (за которой всё равно что) - самодостаточное высказывание.

Comment: Сравнить: Он вошел в дверь и остановился на пороге.  "В пятницу днём Максимилиан Андреевич вошёл в дверь комнаты, в которой помещалось домоуправление дома N 302-бис " [М. А. Булгаков).  Но: Он зашел в дом через парадную дверь.

Answer (score 2):

> > Но замену можно сделать не всегда: "К счастью, никто так и не зашел в дом". В этом случае нельзя сказать "вошел".

Да запросто, почему нет?

> > "Едва я зашел в дверь, которую считал коридорной, как ставня отворилась". Здесь, мне кажется, "зашел" не совсем подходит

Точнее, совсем не подходит. *Зайти* в дверь нельзя.

"Зайти" более близкий синоним к "прийти", чем "войти".
К нему так никто и не зашел (не пришел).

> > Всё-таки наши филологи, которые составляют словари и учат нас культуре речи далеко не всегда внимательны к языку и точны в своих наблюдениях.

Ну уж, ну уж.

Comment: "К счастью, никто так и не зашел в дом".- это все равно что "К счастью, никто так и не вошел в дом"? Ну уж, ну уж.